# C# How to check if array contains a value between 2 integers

Tags: c#, lambda

Given an array {1,4,5,6,7,4,7,8}

How to check if there are values between 4 and 7 ?

Answer (score 9):

```
given.Any(n => n > 4 && n < 7);
```

Feel free to change the `>` and `<` to fall in line with your requirements for exclusivity.

Comment: That's in the eye of the implementer and can easily be done given what I provided.

Comment: Eye of the implementer, eh? `given.Any(n => n > (4 - 0.0000001) && n < (7 + 0.0000001));` Am I doing it right? >.>

Comment: Yes in the eye of the implementer.  `Between` is completely ambiguous between inclusive and exclusive.  And @Chris, since these are all integer types that code will work just fine (although less efficiently) than proper comparators.

Comment: @Servy for sure.  I was just making a (very) bad joke.

Answer (score 5):

```
array.Any(i=>i>=4 && i<=7);
```